# Query a row of data as a column

Tags: sql

I have a table where each row contains 256 values which represent a related series of numeric results. I am querying for a specific row number but want to return the data in a column as the application I am visualizing the data as a graph requires it to be a single column.

For example I query for all 256 columns of data from row number 2 but need the result to be those 256 values in a column. In excel it would be a simple transpose.

I have looked at UNPIVOT function but it doesn't quite seem to fit what I'm trying to do because I'm working with a single column. Maybe I just don't understand how to apply it to this use case. Any advice would be appreciated.

[image: Example Data and Desired Result]

Comment: That is a horrible table design. Can you change it?

Comment: I could ask the person who wrote the test software to try to store the results differently. I'm sure it would take some work but might be possible. How would you suggest storing a large dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join for this purpose (part of the SQL standard).  In SQL Server, this uses the `apply` syntax:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (1, value1), (2, value2), . . ., (256, value256)
     ) v(n, val);
```